# How do I link to database for verifying the username in forget password option

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="" />
```

Trying to implement the 'Forgot Password' option, on this submit button, the username entered must check in to the database and return a message if :-

1. If username exists in DB, return message saying password has been reset and sent to your your registered email id.
2. *This* username does not exist.

How do I call the DB?

Using MVC4 Razor engine.

Thanks.

Code is here:-

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Forgot Password";
}

<h2>Forgot Password</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<fieldset>
    <legend>Forgot Password Form</legend>
    <ol>
        <li>
            @Html.Label("User Name", new { @for = "UserName" })
            @Html.TextBox("UserName")
            <span style="color:red;">@TempData["Message"]</span>
        </li>
    </ol>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="" />

  </fieldset>
```

Comment: Ohk so now? Have you tried something?

Comment: @Mr.Orange Can you post your code ?

Comment: @SurajSingh yes, I have edited. you can see it.

Comment: @Mr.Orange what about controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can call your controller's action method using below code .

```
<input type="button" value="Reset Password" onclick="location.href='<%: Url.Action("Action", "Controller") %>'" />
```

Or you can send your `UserName` value on form submit.

```
  // @using (Html.BeginForm("Hello","Home",FormMethod.Post))
     @using (Html.BeginForm("Action","Controller"))
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Forgot Password Form</legend>
        <ol>
            <li>
                @Html.Label("User Name", new { @for = "UserName" })
                @Html.TextBox("UserName")
                <span style="color:red;">@TempData["Message"]</span>
            </li>
        </ol>
      //<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="" />
      <input type="submit" name="Check" value="Reset Password" />

      </fieldset>
```

---

Controller :

```
   public ActionResult Action(string name)
    {
      string dd = UserName.ToString();
    // Do your call to db or other validation .
      return View();
    }
```